# Best approach using jQuery to get certain values from the HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following page:

```
<body>
...
...
...
  <center>
      <div style="margin-top: -10px; font-size: 8pt; font-weight: bold; color: #909090">2016-04-01</div>
  </center>
  <br>
         <table align="center" width="85%">
            <tbody>
               <tr>
                  <td>
                     <div class="stats-heading">Subscriptions</div>
                     <center>
                        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                           <tbody>
                              <tr>
                                 <td colspan="9" class="datacell">[ 11 total ]</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                 <td class="headingcell">Photo<br>ID</td>
                                 <td class="headingcell">Thumbnail</td>
                                 <td class="headingcell">Downloads</td>
                                 <td class="headingcell">Earned</td>
                                 <td align="center" width="40">
                                    <div style="width: 1px; height: 100%; border-left: 1px solid #E0E0E0"></div>
                                 </td>
                                 <td class="headingcell">Photo<br>ID</td>
                                 <td class="headingcell">Thumbnail</td>
                                 <td class="headingcell">Downloads</td>
                                 <td class="headingcell">Earned</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                 <td class="datacellsm" align="center">
                                    <a class="link" href="http://www.website.com/pic.mhtml?id=117501544" target="pic">117501544</a>
                                 </td>
                                 <td align="center">
                                    <div class="thumb_image_container" style="display: block; width: 100px; height: 67px;   margin: 14px 0px ">
                                       <a onclick="if (window.showPhotoDetails) showPhotoDetails(this); return !window.search" x_website_src="" href="http://www.website.com/pic.mhtml?id=117501544">
                                       <img class="thumb_image" onmouseover="if (window.previewThumb) previewThumb(this)" onmouseout="if (window.cancelPreview) cancelPreview(this)" src="http://thumb1.website.com/thumb_small/1207028/117501544/stock-photo-male-white-tipped-plantcutter-phytotoma-rutila-joi-sa-fafa-america-117501544.jpg" alt="Male White-tipped Plantcutter (Phytotoma rutila). joi, sa, fafa America. - stock photo" title="Male White-tipped Plantcutter (Phytotoma rutila). joi, sa, fafa America. - stock photo" align="absmiddle" border="0" itemprop="image">
                                       </a>
                                    </div>
                                 </td>
                                 <td class="datacell" align="center">1</td>
                                 <td class="datacell" align="center">$0.33</td>
                                 <td align="center" width="40">
                                    <div style="width: 1px; height: 100%; border-left: 1px solid #E0E0E0"></div>
                                 </td>
                                 <td class="datacellsm" align="center">
                                    <a class="link" href="http://www.website.com/pic.mhtml?id=117931651" target="pic">117931651</a>
                                 </td>
                                 <td align="center">
                                    <div class="thumb_image_container" style="display: block; width: 100px; height: 67px;   margin: 14px 0px ">
                                       <a onclick="if (window.showPhotoDetails) showPhotoDetails(this); return !window.search" x_website_src="" href="http://www.website.com/pic.mhtml?id=117931651">
                                       <img class="thumb_image" onmouseover="if (window.previewThumb) previewThumb(this)" onmouseout="if (window.cancelPreview) cancelPreview(this)" src="http://thumb7.website.com/thumb_small/1207028/117931651/stock-photo-yellow-billed-pintail-anas-georgica-swimming-with-reflection-on-water-joi-sa-117931651.jpg" alt="Yellow-billed Pintail (Anas georgica) swimming with reflection on water. joi, sa, fafa America. - stock photo" title="Yellow-billed Pintail (Anas georgica) swimming with reflection on water. joi, sa, fafa America. - stock photo" align="absmiddle" border="0" itemprop="image">
                                       </a>
                                    </div>
                                 </td>
                                 <td class="datacell" align="center">1</td>
                                 <td class="datacell" align="center">$0.33</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                 <td class="datacellsm" align="center">
                                    <a class="link" href="http://www.website.com/pic.mhtml?id=121414813" target="pic">121414813</a>
                                 </td>
                                 <td align="center">
                                    <div class="thumb_image_container" style="display: block; width: 100px; height: 68px;   margin: 14px 0px ">
                                       <a onclick="if (window.showPhotoDetails) showPhotoDetails(this); return !window.search" x_website_src="" href="http://www.website.com/pic.mhtml?id=121414813">
                                       <img class="thumb_image" onmouseover="if (window.previewThumb) previewThumb(this)" onmouseout="if (window.cancelPreview) cancelPreview(this)" src="http://thumb101.website.com/thumb_small/1207028/121414813/stock-photo-sedge-wren-cistothorus-platensis-joi-sa-fafa-america-121414813.jpg" alt="Sedge Wren (Cistothorus platensis), joi, sa, fafa America. - stock photo" title="Sedge Wren (Cistothorus platensis), joi, sa, fafa America. - stock photo" align="absmiddle" border="0" itemprop="image">
                                       </a>
                                    </div>
                                 </td>
                                 <td class="datacell" align="center">1</td>
                                 <td class="datacell" align="center">$0.33</td>
                                 <td align="center" width="40">
                                    <div style="width: 1px; height: 100%; border-left: 1px solid #E0E0E0"></div>
                                 </td>
                                 <td class="datacellsm" align="center">
                                    <a class="link" href="http://www.website.com/pic.mhtml?id=130744133" target="pic">130744133</a>
                                 </td>
                                 <td align="center">
                                    <div class="thumb_image_container" style="display: block; width: 100px; height: 67px;   margin: 14px 0px ">
                                       <a onclick="if (window.showPhotoDetails) showPhotoDetails(this); return !window.search" x_website_src="" href="http://www.website.com/pic.mhtml?id=130744133">
                                       <img class="thumb_image" onmouseover="if (window.previewThumb) previewThumb(this)" onmouseout="if (window.cancelPreview) cancelPreview(this)" src="http://thumb101.website.com/thumb_small/1207028/130744133/stock-photo-two-roseate-spoonbills-platalea-ajaja-balancing-on-a-dead-branch-joi-sa-fafa-130744133.jpg" alt="Two Roseate Spoonbills (Platalea ajaja) balancing on a dead branch. joi, sa, fafa America. - stock photo" title="Two Roseate Spoonbills (Platalea ajaja) balancing on a dead branch. joi, sa, fafa America. - stock photo" align="absmiddle" border="0" itemprop="image">
                                       </a>
                                    </div>
                                 </td>
                                 <td class="datacell" align="center">1</td>
                                 <td class="datacell" align="center">$0.33</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                 <td class="datacellsm" align="center">
                                    <a class="link" href="http://www.website.com/pic.mhtml?id=130744136" target="pic">130744136</a>
                                 </td>
                                 <td align="center">
                                    <div class="thumb_image_container" style="display: block; width: 67px; height: 100px;   margin: 14px 0px ">
                                       <a onclick="if (window.showPhotoDetails) showPhotoDetails(this); return !window.search" x_website_src="" href="http://www.website.com/pic.mhtml?id=130744136">
                                       <img class="thumb_image" onmouseover="if (window.previewThumb) previewThumb(this)" onmouseout="if (window.cancelPreview) cancelPreview(this)" src="http://thumb9.website.com/thumb_small/1207028/130744136/stock-photo-spectacled-tyrant-hymenops-perspicillatus-on-a-dead-branch-joi-sa-fafa-america-130744136.jpg" alt="Spectacled Tyrant (Hymenops perspicillatus) on a dead branch. joi, sa, fafa America. - stock photo" title="Spectacled Tyrant (Hymenops perspicillatus) on a dead branch. joi, sa, fafa America. - stock photo" align="absmiddle" border="0" itemprop="image">
                                       </a>
                                    </div>
                                 </td>
                                 <td class="datacell" align="center">1</td>
                                 <td class="datacell" align="center">$0.33</td>
                                 <td align="center" width="40">
                                    <div style="width: 1px; height: 100%; border-left: 1px solid #E0E0E0"></div>
                                 </td>
                                 <td class="datacellsm" align="center">
                                    <a class="link" href="http://www.website.com/pic.mhtml?id=131579261" target="pic">131579261</a>
                                 </td>
                                 <td align="center">
                                    <div class="thumb_image_container" style="display: block; width: 100px; height: 66px;   margin: 14px 0px ">
                                       <a onclick="if (window.showPhotoDetails) showPhotoDetails(this); return !window.search" x_website_src="" href="http://www.website.com/pic.mhtml?id=131579261">
                                       <img class="thumb_image" onmouseover="if (window.previewThumb) previewThumb(this)" onmouseout="if (window.cancelPreview) cancelPreview(this)" src="http://thumb7.website.com/thumb_small/1207028/131579261/stock-photo-acoustic-guitar-with-very-shallow-depth-of-field-focus-on-strings-black-white-131579261.jpg" alt="Acoustic Guitar with very shallow depth of field, focus on strings. Black &amp; White - stock photo" title="Acoustic Guitar with very shallow depth of field, focus on strings. Black &amp; White - stock photo" align="absmiddle" border="0" itemprop="image">
                                       </a>
                                    </div>
                                 </td>
                                 <td class="datacell" align="center">1</td>
                                 <td class="datacell" align="center">$0.33</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                 <td class="datacellsm" align="center">
                                    <a class="link" href="http://www.website.com/pic.mhtml?id=183273761" target="pic">183273761</a>
                                 </td>
                                 <td align="center">
                                    <div class="thumb_image_container" style="display: block; width: 75px; height: 100px;   margin: 14px 0px ">
                                       <a onclick="if (window.showPhotoDetails) showPhotoDetails(this); return !window.search" x_website_src="" href="http://www.website.com/pic.mhtml?id=183273761">
                                       <img class="thumb_image" onmouseover="if (window.previewThumb) previewThumb(this)" onmouseout="if (window.cancelPreview) cancelPreview(this)" src="http://thumb7.website.com/thumb_small/1207028/183273761/stock-photo-illioneus-giant-owl-caligo-illioneus-pampeiro-butterfly-resting-in-a-tree-s-bark-paranaense-183273761.jpg" alt="Illioneus Giant Owl (Caligo illioneus pampeiro) butterfly resting in a tree's bark. Paranaense forest, Misiones, sa, fafa America - stock photo" title="Illioneus Giant Owl (Caligo illioneus pampeiro) butterfly resting in a tree's bark. Paranaense forest, Misiones, sa, fafa America - stock photo" align="absmiddle" border="0" itemprop="image">
                                       </a>
                                    </div>
                                 </td>
                                 <td class="datacell" align="center">1</td>
                                 <td class="datacell" align="center">$0.33</td>
                                 <td align="center" width="40">
                                    <div style="width: 1px; height: 100%; border-left: 1px solid #E0E0E0"></div>
                                 </td>
                                 <td class="datacellsm" align="center">
                                    <a class="link" href="http://www.website.com/pic.mhtml?id=232608718" target="pic">232608718</a>
                                 </td>
                                 <td align="center">
                                    <div class="thumb_image_container" style="display: block; width: 67px; height: 100px;   margin: 14px 0px ">
                                       <a onclick="if (window.showPhotoDetails) showPhotoDetails(this); return !window.search" x_website_src="" href="http://www.website.com/pic.mhtml?id=232608718">
                                       <img class="thumb_image" onmouseover="if (window.previewThumb) previewThumb(this)" onmouseout="if (window.cancelPreview) cancelPreview(this)" src="http://thumb1.website.com/thumb_small/1207028/232608718/stock-photo-many-coloured-rush-tyrant-tachuris-rubrigastra-perched-on-reed-over-water-joi-sa-232608718.jpg" alt="Many-coloured Rush Tyrant (Tachuris rubrigastra) perched on reed over water. joi, sa, fafa America. - stock photo" title="Many-coloured Rush Tyrant (Tachuris rubrigastra) perched on reed over water. joi, sa, fafa America. - stock photo" align="absmiddle" border="0" itemprop="image">
                                       </a>
                                    </div>
                                 </td>
                                 <td class="datacell" align="center">1</td>
                                 <td class="datacell" align="center">$0.33</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                 <td class="datacellsm" align="center">
                                    <a class="link" href="http://www.website.com/pic.mhtml?id=238411516" target="pic">238411516</a>
                                 </td>
                                 <td align="center">
                                    <div class="thumb_image_container" style="display: block; width: 100px; height: 66px;   margin: 14px 0px ">
                                       <a onclick="if (window.showPhotoDetails) showPhotoDetails(this); return !window.search" x_website_src="" href="http://www.website.com/pic.mhtml?id=238411516">
                                       <img class="thumb_image" onmouseover="if (window.previewThumb) previewThumb(this)" onmouseout="if (window.cancelPreview) cancelPreview(this)" src="http://thumb9.website.com/thumb_small/1207028/238411516/stock-photo-raw-organic-amaranth-grains-in-a-wooden-spoon-238411516.jpg" alt="Raw organic Amaranth grains in a wooden spoon. - stock photo" title="Raw organic Amaranth grains in a wooden spoon. - stock photo" align="absmiddle" border="0" itemprop="image">
                                       </a>
                                    </div>
                                 </td>
                                 <td class="datacell" align="center">1</td>
                                 <td class="datacell" align="center">$0.33</td>
                                 <td align="center" width="40">
                                    <div style="width: 1px; height: 100%; border-left: 1px solid #E0E0E0"></div>
                                 </td>
                                 <td class="datacellsm" align="center">
                                    <a class="link" href="http://www.website.com/pic.mhtml?id=238411519" target="pic">238411519</a>
                                 </td>
                                 <td align="center">
                                    <div class="thumb_image_container" style="display: block; width: 100px; height: 66px;   margin: 14px 0px ">
                                       <a onclick="if (window.showPhotoDetails) showPhotoDetails(this); return !window.search" x_website_src="" href="http://www.website.com/pic.mhtml?id=238411519">
                                       <img class="thumb_image" onmouseover="if (window.previewThumb) previewThumb(this)" onmouseout="if (window.cancelPreview) cancelPreview(this)" src="http://thumb7.website.com/thumb_small/1207028/238411519/stock-photo-raw-organic-amaranth-grains-texture-background-238411519.jpg" alt="Raw organic Amaranth grains. Texture. Background. - stock photo" title="Raw organic Amaranth grains. Texture. Background. - stock photo" align="absmiddle" border="0" itemprop="image">
                                       </a>
                                    </div>
                                 </td>
                                 <td class="datacell" align="center">1</td>
                                 <td class="datacell" align="center">$0.33</td>
                              </tr>
                              <tr>
                                 <td class="datacellsm" align="center">
                                    <a class="link" href="http://www.website.com/pic.mhtml?id=238987900" target="pic">238987900</a>
                                 </td>
                                 <td align="center">
                                    <div class="thumb_image_container" style="display: block; width: 77px; height: 100px;   margin: 14px 0px ">
                                       <a onclick="if (window.showPhotoDetails) showPhotoDetails(this); return !window.search" x_website_src="" href="http://www.website.com/pic.mhtml?id=238987900">
                                       <img class="thumb_image" onmouseover="if (window.previewThumb) previewThumb(this)" onmouseout="if (window.cancelPreview) cancelPreview(this)" src="http://thumb1.website.com/thumb_small/1207028/238987900/stock-photo-sephanoides-sephaniodes-feeding-on-a-quintral-s-tristerix-tetrandrus-nectar-joi-sa-238987900.jpg" alt="Sephanoides sephaniodes feeding on a Quintral's (Tristerix tetrandrus) nectar. joi, sa, fafa America. - stock photo" title="Sephanoides sephaniodes feeding on a Quintral's (Tristerix tetrandrus) nectar. joi, sa, fafa America. - stock photo" align="absmiddle" border="0" itemprop="image">
                                       </a>
                                    </div>
                                 </td>
                                 <td class="datacell" align="center">1</td>
                                 <td class="datacell" align="center">$0.33</td>
                                 <td align="center" width="40">
                                    <div style="width: 1px; height: 100%; border-left: 1px solid #E0E0E0"></div>
                                 </td>
                              </tr>
                           </tbody>
                        </table>
                     </center>
                     <br><br>
                     <div class="stats-heading">On Demand Downloads</div>
                     <br>
                     <center>
                        <div style="font-weight: bold; color: #585858; font-size: 7pt; margin: 25px 0px">None of your pictures were downloaded from an On Demand account on this date.</div>
                     </center>
                     <div class="stats-heading">Enhanced Downloads</div>
                     <br>
                     <center>
                        <div style="font-weight: bold; color: #585858; font-size: 7pt; margin: 25px 0px">None of your pictures were downloaded via an Enhanced subscription on this date.</div>
                     </center>
                     <div class="stats-heading"></div>
                     <div class="stats-heading">Referred Downloads</div>
                     <style type="text/css">
                        .stats-figure {
                        padding: 2px; 
                        font-size: 11px; 
                        color: #70a040;
                        }
                     </style>
                     <div class="stats-message">
                        None of your <a href="/refinfo.mhtml">referred photographers</a> had downloads on this date.    
                     </div>
                     <div class="stats-heading">Referred Footage</div>
                     <style type="text/css">
                        .stats-figure {
                        padding: 2px; 
                        font-size: 11px; 
                        color: #70a040;
                        }
                     </style>
                     <div class="stats-message">
                        None of your <a href="/reffootage.mhtml">referred videographers</a> had downloads on this date. 
                     </div>
                     <div class="stats-heading">Referred Orders</div>
                     <style type="text/css">
                        .stats-figure {
                        padding: 2px; 
                        font-size: 11px; 
                        color: #70a040;
                        }
                     </style>
                     <div class="stats-message">
                        You didn't <a href="/reforder.mhtml">refer any photo buyers</a> on this date.   
                     </div>
                     <div class="stats-heading">Footage Cart Sales</div>
                     <table align="center" width="85%">
                        <tbody>
                           <tr>
                              <td>
                                 <center>
                                    <div class="stats-message">None of your footage clips were downloaded via shopping cart on this date.</div>
                                 </center>
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                        </tbody>
                     </table>
                     <div class="stats-heading">Clip Packs</div>
                     <table align="center" width="85%">
                        <tbody>
                           <tr>
                              <td>
                                 <center>
                                    <div class="stats-message">None of your footage clips were downloaded via subscription on this date.</div>
                                 </center>
                              </td>
                           </tr>
                        </tbody>
                     </table>
                     <div class="stats-heading">Single &amp; Other Downloads</div>
                     <br>
                     <center>
                        <div style="font-weight: bold; color: #585858; font-size: 7pt; margin: 25px 0px">No images downloaded yet</div>
                     </center>
                     <div class="stats-heading">Delayed Earnings</div>
                     <div class="stats-message">You have 0 <a href="delayed_earnings.mhtml">delayed earning(s)</a> on this day, for $0.</div>
                  </td>
               </tr>
            </tbody>
         </table>
         <p>
         </p>
      </div>
...
...
</body>
```

Within this html are a few `TR` elements like this one:

```
<tr>
   <td class="datacellsm" align="center">
      <a class="link" href="http://www.website.com/pic.mhtml?id=117501544" target="pic">117501544</a>
   </td>
   <td align="center">
      <div class="thumb_image_container" style="display: block; width: 100px; height: 67px;   margin: 14px 0px ">
         <a onclick="if (window.showPhotoDetails) showPhotoDetails(this); return !window.search" x_website_src="" href="http://www.website.com/pic.mhtml?id=117501544">
         <img class="thumb_image" onmouseover="if (window.previewThumb) previewThumb(this)" onmouseout="if (window.cancelPreview) cancelPreview(this)" src="http://thumb1.website.com/thumb_small/1207028/117501544/stock-photo-male-white-tipped-plantcutter-phytotoma-rutila-joi-sa-fafa-america-117501544.jpg" alt="Male White-tipped Plantcutter (Phytotoma rutila). joi, sa, fafa America. - stock photo" title="Male White-tipped Plantcutter (Phytotoma rutila). joi, sa, fafa America. - stock photo" align="absmiddle" border="0" itemprop="image">
         </a>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td class="datacell" align="center">1</td>
   <td class="datacell" align="center">$0.33</td>
   <td align="center" width="40">
      <div style="width: 1px; height: 100%; border-left: 1px solid #E0E0E0"></div>
   </td>
   <td class="datacellsm" align="center">
      <a class="link" href="http://www.website.com/pic.mhtml?id=117931651" target="pic">117931651</a>
   </td>
   <td align="center">
      <div class="thumb_image_container" style="display: block; width: 100px; height: 67px;   margin: 14px 0px ">
         <a onclick="if (window.showPhotoDetails) showPhotoDetails(this); return !window.search" x_website_src="" href="http://www.website.com/pic.mhtml?id=117931651">
         <img class="thumb_image" onmouseover="if (window.previewThumb) previewThumb(this)" onmouseout="if (window.cancelPreview) cancelPreview(this)" src="http://thumb7.website.com/thumb_small/1207028/117931651/stock-photo-yellow-billed-pintail-anas-georgica-swimming-with-reflection-on-water-joi-sa-117931651.jpg" alt="Yellow-billed Pintail (Anas georgica) swimming with reflection on water. joi, sa, fafa America. - stock photo" title="Yellow-billed Pintail (Anas georgica) swimming with reflection on water. joi, sa, fafa America. - stock photo" align="absmiddle" border="0" itemprop="image">
         </a>
      </div>
   </td>
   <td class="datacell" align="center">1</td>
   <td class="datacell" align="center">$0.33</td>
</tr>
```

From each of those `<TR>` elements I need to get the value of the first `TD`, the one that contains the ID. In the previous example: 117501544

Also the value of some (not all) other `TD`s, as for example the one that contains the price: $0.33.

Comment: Do you have control over the generation of the html?

Comment: No, I don't have control over the generation process...

Comment: So this isn't just for one row.  You need a way to do this for each row?

Comment: Yes, that's right. And the number of rows is unknown. May go from 0 to 500.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a shame you can't control the resultant html as it appears to be a bit of a mess from the snippet you included.

Here's a rough version of what I threw together with your html snippet on jsfiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/k8q9bmqz/1/).  I'm sure it's not the best / most elegant way.

I've included the code below to explain:

```
$('table table > tbody > tr').each(function() {
var $id = $(this).find('td a[target="pic"]:first');
if($id.length > 0)
{
  alert($id.text());
  alert($id.parent().siblings().next().next().html());
}
});
```

The jquery selector on the first line skips the first table since it appears to only be for layout, grabs the second table's tbody and all it's rows since according to your question this is where your items are.  The selector's results are immediately looped over.

```
$('table table > tbody > tr').each(function() {
```

In the loop (for each row), we find the first column that has an anchor with the target attribute of pic.  We grab the first one only as you specified since the row is displaying two items side by side.

```
var $id = $(this).find('td a[target="pic"]:first');
```

The search may not be successful as the first two table rows are used as table headers so we check to see that it is.

```
if($id.length > 0)
```

Upon success we display the anchor tags text and then grab the price by traversing up the found id anchor's parent table column and then telling jquery to get all of this column's siblings and go to the second sibling from it to get the price.

```
alert($id.text());
alert($id.parent().siblings().next().next().html());
```

Answer (score 0):

i would propably do it this way: https://jsfiddle.net/r4m2ha06/4/

```
  function getPhotoEarnings(){
      var earnings = [];
      var relevantTable = $("a[class='link']").closest("table");
      var trs = relevantTable.find("tr");
      for(var i=2;i<trs.length-1;i++){
          var tds = $(trs[i]).find("td");
          var firstId = $(tds[0]).find("a").html();
          var firstName = $(tds[1]).find("img").attr("title");
          var firstEarned = $(tds[3]).html();
          var secondId = $(tds[5]).find("a").html();
          var secondName = $(tds[6]).find("img").attr("title");
          var secondEarned = $(tds[8]).html();
          earnings.push({
            "id":firstId,
            "name":firstName,
            "earned":firstEarned
          });
          earnings.push({
           "id":secondId,
           "name":secondName,
           "earned":secondEarned
          });
      }
    return earnings;
}
```

it is of course not the shortest or fastest solution but you can change the code easily when the source html changes.